# Is any other possibility to create threads, tasks in Java which not extend Thread or implement Runnable, Callable<V>?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know three ways of creation threads, tasks in Java. In job interview one guy asked me if it is possible to create thread in Java in other way. Is it is possible? If is, please put some example.

Comment: I dnt think thr is any other thn this 3.

Comment: For me, it is not clear what is meant by 'Thread' here. A class implementing `Runnable` is NOT a Thread. (Often, it is executed by a new Thread, but not necessarily). Consequently, the only way to 'create a thread' is to instantiate a `new Thead` (or a class extending `Thread`, and to call `start` on it...)

Comment: well you could use JNI, but I assume it doesn't count as using Java...

Comment: The answer to "Is it possible?" is always: "Yes". The correct question however is: "Is it reasonable?"

Comment: Well, since this is an interview question, I would certainly ask him to be more specific.  There's a difference between a Java `Thread` and any old "task".  It's of course possible to start new tasks and processes.

Comment: You know three ways such as what? How do you expect to be told what the others are, if any, when you don't tell us the ones you already know?

Answer (score 11):

The only way to create a thread in Java is by creating a `Thread` object and [starting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) it.

Quoting [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html):

> The only way for a user to create a thread is to create an object of this class; each thread is associated with such an object. A thread will start when the start() method is invoked on the corresponding Thread object.

`Runnable` and `Callable` are two interfaces that the JDK uses for submitting code to be executed in threads. For example, in its various [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: added a quote from jls to confirm that it's actually the only way

Comment: 'Runnable' is not only used for submitting code to be executed by the 'java.util.concurrent' classes. 'Runnable' has been used long before the 'java.util.concurrent' classes were introduced. 'Runnable' is widely used in Swing programming without having to submit code foe execution in the 'java.util.concurrent' classes. Look at [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) for example .

Comment: @user454322 One does not exclude the other. Yes, `Runnable` has existed since the beginning of Java, but it is not a way of creating threads. The `SwingUtilities` methods that accept `Runnable` arguments are meant to be run either synchronously on the event dispatching thread or asynchronously on some other thread. I've fixed my answer to be more clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

`Runnable`, by convention, is an interface accepted for arguments to Thread's constructor. You can extend Thread so that constructors of child class accept any other type of argument. Similary, `Callable` is accepted by thread pools in java.util.concurrent. You can develop other kinds of thread pools, which accept any other types of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a thread anonymously. For example as given below :

```
import java.util.Date;
class TestDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println(new Date());
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: That still constitutes creating a thread object, and it isn't clear whether the OP already knows this one or not.